# SQL Left join same table but with condition possible?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, conditional-statements

I have a main Table

```
|-------------|------------|
| Procedure   | Modifier   |
|:------------|:-----------|
|     AA      |     00     |
|     AA      |     21     |
|     AA      |     26     |
|-------------|------------|
```

and a rates Table

```
|-------------|------------|-------|
| Procedure   | Modifier   | Rate  |
|:------------|:-----------|-------|
|     AA      |     00     | $10   |
|     AA      |     21     | $20   |
|     AA      |     QA     | $30   |
|-------------|------------|-------|
```

I am looking to left join the rate table to main table ON procedure AND modifier, to find the rate.

However, if there is no matching procedure AND modifier, then I want to join by procedure and modifier 00 to get the rate of $10.

End result to look like this,
|

```
-------------|------------|------|
| Procedure   | Modifier   | Rate |
|:------------|:-----------|------|
|     AA      |     00     |$10   |
|     AA      |     21     |$20   |
|     AA      |     26     |$10   |
|-------------|------------|------|
```

NOT

```
|-------------|------------|------|
| Procedure   | Modifier   | Rate |
|:------------|:-----------|------|
|     AA      |     00     |$10   |
|     AA      |     21     |$20   |
|     AA      |     26     |null  |
|-------------|------------|------|
```

I suppose 'worse' case is to do this separately and split into two statements. Where my first left join would be by proc and modifier then later in my second statement just by procedure? Is there a way to do this within one statement?

Comment: I will try next time! I really appreciate everyone's input, I think John had edited my posting immediately (because my tables didn't turn out the way they look now). Being new to all this, will do!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can do this nice and simple with two left-joins.**

Note that this is very similar to Kazi's answer, just with a much more straightforward syntax

```sql
select
    m.[Procedure],
    m.Modifier,
    isnull(r.rate, r2.rate) rate
from maintable m
left join rates r on m.[Procedure] = r.[Procedure] and m.Modifier = r.Modifier  
left join rates r2 on m.[Procedure] = r2.[Procedure]
    and r2.Modifier = '00'
    and r.rate is null
```

Comment: @Schen . . . This is the best solution.

Comment: I just test ran this and it works, agree it is more straightforward to read. Note that I had to change Charie's syntax on r.Modifier = '00' to 'r2.Modifier = '00' .  Thank you Charlie and Gordon for your inputs!

Comment: Smart one @Charlieface. But wouldn't it be slower? Just curiosity.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur 99% sure this will optimize the same as your first query, it may even be better as yours could end up forcing a nested loops join. Your second query could also be rewritten as a left join with the same effect, the only difference is that that doesn't have the bail-out condition based on the first join

Comment: @Charlieface there is no doubt I would go for your answer and I liked it very much. I even upvoted it. But when I tried it in sql server on OP's provided data it's taking 60% time when solution with subquery is taken 40%. That's why I asked. Will this change with increase in rows? Thinks so. That's why this friendly discussion. Just to learn more.

Comment: @KaziMohammadAliNur How are you timing it, OP only gave 3 rows? Or are you basing off the estimated plan, because that is pretty unreliable? Yes, more rows makes a big difference, with a lot of rows, you want a merge or hash join, which could be difficult for your query. Note that the optimizer is very capable of transforming between a join and a basic correlated apply/subquery, so syntax doesn't really matter unless the apply has other calculations such as `top` or `over`

Comment: Thought so. Have a nice day @Charlieface (Though I don't know your time zone :)).

Answer (score 0):

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table maintable ([Procedure]   varchar(10), Modifier   varchar(10));
 insert into maintable values(     'AA'  ,        '00');     
 insert into maintable values(     'AA' ,         '21');
 insert into maintable values(     'AA',          '26'); 
 
 create table  rates ( [Procedure]   varchar(10), Modifier   varchar(10), Rate  varchar(10));
 insert into rates values(     'AA'        ,   '00',      '$10');
 insert into rates values(     'AA'       ,    '21' ,     '$20');
 insert into rates values(     'AA'      ,     'QA'  ,    '$30');
```

Query#1 (with subquery):

```
     select m.[Procedure]   , m.Modifier ,(case when r.rate is null then (select rate from rates where rates.[procedure]=m.[procedure] and rates.modifier='00') else r.rate  end)rate
     from maintable m
     left join rates r on m.[Procedure]  =r.[Procedure]   and    m.Modifier  =r.Modifier
```

Output:

| Procedure | Modifier | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 00 | $10 |
| AA | 21 | $20 |
| AA | 26 | $10 |

Query#2 (with outer apply):

```
     select m.[Procedure]   , m.Modifier ,(case when r.rate is null then t.rate else r.rate  end)rate
     from maintable m
     left join rates r on m.[Procedure]  =r.[Procedure]   and    m.Modifier  =r.Modifier  
     outer apply(select rate from rates where rates.[Procedure]=m.[Procedure] and rates.modifier='00')t
```

Output:

| Procedure | Modifier | rate |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AA | 00 | $10 |
| AA | 21 | $20 |
| AA | 26 | $10 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=68717cdee4dfe9f025a06acdad1bb818)*

Comment: Thank you Kazi! I love this solution, being new to sql I think I got fixated on the idea that I am joining on a 'condition' so my solution 'MUST' involve a CASE statement or something.. thank you!

Comment: Extremely sorry to let you know that my previous solution wouldn't work. I have changed my answer.

Comment: @DaleK after you suggestion I always try to remove (>) but sometimes lack of time does that. Then I try to edit my answer later.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a CASE statement. The example below does a left join from the rate table on the main table matching procedure and modifier.  The case statement replaces null values with 10 or uses the rate if it exists.

```
select 
    m.procedure,
    m.modifier,
    case when r.rate is null then 10 else r.rate end as rate
from main_table m
left join rates_table r on (m.procedure = r.procedure and m.modifier = r.modifier)
```

Comment: Sorry I did not specify that for next set of procedure it might not be 10.  But if the default is always 10 then this is a neat faster(?) solution. Thank you both.

Comment: I assume you meant a `case` *expression*? Since SQL Server doesn't have a `case` *statement* :)

Answer (score 0):

A variant on this is to use an apply operator instead of a correlated subquery in the select clause, and instead of a case expression it is also possible to use coalesce, and here 10 can be used if there is no matching rate from either the left join or the outer apply:

```
select 
     m.[procedure]
   , m.modifier
   , coalesce(r.rate, oa.rate, 10) as rate
from maintable m
left join rates r on m.[procedure] = r.[procedure] and m.modifier = r.modifier
outer apply (
    select rate 
    from rates 
    where rates.[procedure]=m.[procedure] and rates.modifier='00'
    ) oa
```

Comment: I can only test this solution and it works! Although I don't fully understand outer apply, yet, I will look up and better understand first before using, thank you for introducing this neat alternative!